# $PV^\gamma = {\rm constant}$

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

At adiabatic state, I know that $PV^\gamma = \rm constant$, but why is it also equal to $P_1V_1^\gamma=P_2V_2^\gamma$?

edit : how do i know that p1v1^gamma is equal to the same constant that p2v2^gamma is equal to, there's unlimited number of constants how do i know that they have the same constant?

Comment: What else do you think equating something to a constant means?

Comment: https://opentextbc.ca/universityphysicsv2openstax/chapter/adiabatic-processes-for-an-ideal-gas/

Comment: how do i know that p1v1^gamma is equal to the same constant that p2v2^gamma is equal to,
there's unlimited number of constants 
how do i know that they have the same constant?
what is the proof of it?
is my question clear now?

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and ($x_{2},y_{2}$) lie on the same line $ax+by+c=0$ then both of these relations will hold.
$$ax_{1}+by_{1}+c=0$$
$$ax_{2}+by_{2}+c=0$$
Likewise $(P_{1},V_{1})$ and $(P_{2},V_{2})$ lying on the same adiabatic curve will satisfy the given relation. It will be true for any point lying on the curve.

Comment: I got it,many thanks!